# dotnet core web app unit test controller

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a dotnetcore web app and am looking to unit test the controllers.  How do I get about this?

I have a simple controller that looks like this

```
public class ConversionController : Controller {
    private readonly INumberService _numberService;

    public ConversionController(INumberService numberService)
    {
        this._numberService = numberService;
    }

    // GET http://localhost:9789/api/conversion/123
    [HttpGet("{number}")]
    public string Get(decimal number)
    {
        return _numberService.ConvertToWords(number);
    }
}
```

The `INumberService` is passed in as a parameter.  How do I unit test this?

Answer (score 1):

By mocking the interface/dependency and exercising an isolated unit test for the Get method. You could either create your own mock or use a mocking framework to mock the dependency. From there assert that the system under test behaves as expected.

For example the following simple test uses [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) to mock the dependency and test the `Get` method.

```
[TestMethod]
public void ConversionController_Get_Should_Return_Five() {
    //Arrange
    var number = 5;
    var expected = "five";
    var mock = new Mock<INumberService>();
    mock.Setup(_ => _.ConvertToWords(number)).Returns(expected);
    var sut = new ConversionController(mock.Object);

    //Act
    var actual = sut.Get(number);

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

You should also take some time and check the documentation provided

[Unit Testing in .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/)